# Outlook email iteration using PowerShell very slow in VDI

Tags: powershell, outlook, vdi

I have been trying to iterate emails inside a shared folder in outlook application running on VDI using Power-Shell, but the iteration of emails is very slow... Please Help.

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you post your code and maybe give more specifics of what you're doing, what troubleshooting you've tried, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response... Apparently I am running a windows powershell script inside a VDI... Powershell script is fetching emails from a shared folder in outlook application using  outlook application ComObject and iterating over each one of them to look for some specific received time of the email however, the same script is working perfectly fine when executing on a local machine.